# Test Suite Python - issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest, test-suite

Currently I am reading the book Learning Selenium with Python and I'm having trouble running a suite. Below I will post my two test classes and my file that contains the suite.

**searchproducts.py**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a054c6c8728d91f9ad8

**homepagetest.py**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5043f2432f2316345c3f

**smoketest.py**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8220d861fce77d0ea197

When I try run the smoketest.py file, is shown the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "smoketests.py", line 12, in <module>
 unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(smoke_tests)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib' /python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 151, in run
test(result)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib  /python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 70, in __call__
return self.run(*args, **kwds)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 108, in run
test(result)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 50, in loadTestsFromTestCase
if issubclass(testCaseClass, suite.TestSuite):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the `loadTestsFromTestCase`.
But this change works for me:

```
search_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(SearchTests, )
home_page_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(HomePageTest, )
```